# How can I use a UTF-16 encoded Signature with RDO

Tags: delphi, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to use a UTF-16 encoded Signature in an Email.
The Files are in the usual Place (%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures).
When I use the signature in Outlook it works but when I try to create the Mail using RDO I only see the BOM (ÿþ<)

```
LMail    := Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items.Add(olMailItem);
LSession := Session.Signatures.Item('SignatureName');
LSignature.ApplyTo(LMail, False);
LMail.Display(True, 0);
```

I thought that Setting LMail.InternetCodepage might help but this has had no effect.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you email the signature and its files to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com. Thanks!